# Why is this blob saving when used as a concatenated string but not as a prepared statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, php, mysqli

I have a PHP mysqli prepared statement that looks like this:

```
$editSQL = "UPDATE tblClientReminders
              SET Header = ?, Notes = ?, DepartmentID = ?,
                  TierID = ?, RemindType = ?, RemindDate = ?, DateAdded = ?
              WHERE ReminderID = ?";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($editSQL);
     $stmt->bind_param('sbiiissi', $input[1], $input[2], $input[3],
             $input[4], $input[5], $input[6],
             $DateAdded, $_SESSION[$thisTracker]);
     $DateAdded = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
```

When I run this, it executes without throwing any errors and runs everything else as expected; however, the "Notes" field is cleared even though $input[2] has content.  But when I do this using concatenation:

```
$editSQL = "UPDATE tblClientReminders
         SET Header = '".$input[1]."', Notes = '".$input[2]."',
             DepartmentID = '".$input[3]."', TierID = '".$input[4]."',
             RemindType = '".$input[5]."', RemindDate = '".$input[6]."',
             DateAdded = '".date("Y-m-d h:i:s")."'
         WHERE ReminderID = '".$_SESSION[$thisTracker]."'";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($editSQL);       
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
```

$input[2] is properly saved along with everything else.  I have verified that the column "Notes" is a blob in the mySQL database, and that $input[2] actually contains the intended data when I try the prepared statement.  So, why is $input[2] not saving in the first example, and how would I fix that.

The only other factor here I can think of is that $input[2] is passing an AES string, but I can't think of why that would be a problem since other queries elsewhere in my code are saving AES strings just fine, but I think this is the only one that does it to a blob.

**An example of inputs:**

```
$input[1] = 'test';
$input[2] = '8L2G1urlEQEjZdyMrSQeow==::88f32b3584167b1d7286a57f861d4fd6';
$input[3] = 1;
$input[4] = 3;
$input[5] = 0;
$input[6] = '2018-11-20';
$_SESSION[$thisTracker] = 15;
```

Comment: Please provide a sample value, including punctuation, for `$input[2]`.  Off hand, I would expect the second to fail, not the first.

Comment: Added an example AES string, as far as raw input goes, even simple numbers and strings like `123` and `test` are failing.

Comment: That is, the value is plain ascii, no specific need for `BLOB`.  And there are no quotes or apostrophes, so no need (aside from SQL Injection prevention) to need "prepare".  Can you provide a failing test case?  Just a one-column table with one input value to insert?  No mention of $_SESSION.  Variables set to constant values, etc.

Comment: A simplification:  `DateAdded = '".date("Y-m-d h:i:s")."'` --> `DateAdded = NOW()`

Comment: Input[1] is a non-encrypted string; so, it does need to be prepared to prevent injection.  I might be able to simply concatenate just input[2] since it is encoded, but I'd rather fix it than work around it if at all possible.  Some of the data handled by this system may need to meet various security compliance standards; so, I'd rather not have to explain it in a security audit.

Comment: AES encryption is not a security solution -- What if the injection happened before the encryption, then you "echo" or otherwise feed it to MySQL (SQL injection) or to HTML (JavaScript tricks).

Comment: Encryption can prevent SQL injection, but not XSS when it is encrypted and decrypted at the application layer.  The PHP takes the whole variable as an executable value (just like a prepared statement does), and encodes it such that it's all just meaningless hex strings, then you wait till it comes back to your PHP to decrypt it. That way, special characters never hit your database.  The data of those inputs is also already sanitized elsewhere against that XSS, but even while it's just as secure... it's still a red flag on an audit. So, not very recommended.

Comment: Encryption at the database layer is not a security feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`bind_param` page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) mentions (emphasis mine) for the `types` parameter that

> corresponding variable is a blob and *will be sent in packets*

which is done in this manner:

```
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param('sbiiissi', $input[1], $null, $input[3],
         $input[4], $input[5], $input[6],
         $DateAdded, $_SESSION[$thisTracker]);
$stmt->send_long_data(1, $input[2]);
```

If your BLOB data exceeds the `max_allowed_packet` size you will need to call `send_long_data` multiple times, sending a smaller fragment of it each time.

More info in [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/phps-mysqli-extension:-storing-and-retrieving-blobs).

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! but $stmt->send_long_data(0, $input[2]); should be $stmt->send_long_data(1, $input[2]);  The first input is the array location of your inputs starting with zero; so, while it should be zero your example, in my case it is 1.  Just an important distinction for people following up on this.

Comment: How about turning on the general log so we can see this in action.

Comment: @Nosajimiki sorry, that was a typo.